# How to force logout of all users on VSS?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, logout, visual-sourcesafe-2005

VSS is resuming it's sabotage of my repository again. The repair command won't let me repair, the lock VSS doesn't seem to affect currently logged in users-- and it isn't a user, its claiming the only person logged in is admin (via the VSS admin tool!) and I have already closed all instances of the VSS admin tool and client.

Comment: I generally hate doing this sort of thing (which is why this is a comment and not an answer) but have you considered moving away from VSS?

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html (Source Control:  Anything but Sourcesafe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer management, close all the sessions and open files.  It's drastic, but that is the only way I found to fix it.  You also might want to close the share temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and even after following the steps in the answer above, it did not go away until I **stop**ped the **SQLWriter** (Sql Server VSS Writer) and **SSService** (Visual SourceSafe LAN Service) services.

Answer (score 1):

Write a mail to everyone:

**Subject**: VSS Emergency

**Body**: Everyone is asked to disconnect immediately from VSS. This is not a drill. I repeat: this is not a drill.

Comment: ha ha.  I sent the email to the administrator-- the only person logged in. That was me.  I told my self I didn't have the answer, so please contact the administrator. That put me into an infinite loop I may never get out of.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the machine and re-try.

Answer (score 1):

Close also all Visual Studio instances since these are also (or can be) clients of Visual Source Safe.

Answer (score 1):

stopping SSService (Visual SourceSafe LAN Service)  worked for me, thanks.

it saved lot of time and confusions...

Answer (score 1):

I have this batch file running through the Task Scheduler 2:00 a.m. every day when no one should be logged in anyway, but they are.  It seems to do the trick.

```
net stop sqlwriter
net stop ssservice
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\analyze.exe" -C -D -F -V4 "D:\vss\data"
net start ssservice
net start sqlwriter
```

The only issue I have come across is the backup folder might have data in it, which stops analyzer in its tracks.  So I might end up adding some commands to move the stuff out of the data\backup folder if I run into that issue again.  (In that scenario, you have to keep the analyze.log file in the backup folder.  I haven't done enough research into that, though.)

I hope this helps!

Comment: -bd cmd option will remove the last backup.  I use it anyways after renaming the backup folder by appending a timestamp.  Analyze.exe -F -V3 -D -db -c -s "Drive:\Location".

Comment: Thank you, Tamus.  I will try that out, but how do you go about renaming the backup folder by appending a timestamp?  I did add such a feature to my batch file, but it seems that it only creates the folder without moving the backup data into it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open 'Microsoft Visual SourceSafe Administration'.
2. Select user and change password (if required) from User > Change password.
3. Tools > Options > Untick 'Use network name for automatic use log in' > OK.
4. Open 'Microsoft Visual SourceSafe' and login with the required user then do 'undo check out' or 'check-in' for required file(s).